# Match all occurrences of a string

Tags: php, regex, perl, preg-match-all

My search text is as follows.

```
...
...
var strings = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"];
...
...
```

It contains many lines(actually a javascript file) but need to parse the values in variable *strings* , ie aaa , bbb, ccc , ddd , eee

Following is the Perl code, or use PHP at bottom

```
my $str = <<STR;
    ...
    ...
    var strings = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"];
    ...
    ...
STR

my @matches = $str =~ /(?:\"(.+?)\",?)/g;
print "@matches";
```

I know the above script will match all instants, but it will parse strings (*"xyz"*) in the other lines also. So I need to check the string *var strings =*

```
/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)/g
```

Using above regex it will parse *aaa*.

```
/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)(?:\"(.+?)\",?)/g
```

Using above, will get *aaa* , and *bbb*. So to avoid the regex repeating I used '+' quantifier as below.

```
/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)+/g
```

But I got only *eee*, So **my question is why I got *eee* ONLY when I used '+' quantifier?**

Update 1: Using PHP preg_match_all (doing it to get more attention :-) )

```
$str = <<<STR
    ...
    ...
    var strings = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"];
    ...
    ...
STR;

preg_match_all("/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)+/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Update 2: Why it matched *eee* ? Because of the greediness of `(?:\"(.+?)\",?)+` . By removing greediness `/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)+?/` *aaa* will be matched. **But why only one result? Is there any way it can be achieved by using single regex?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a single-regex solution:

```
/(?:\bvar\s+strings\s*=\s*\[|\G,)\s*"([^"]*)"/g
```

`\G` is a zero-width assertion that matches the position where the previous match ended  (or the beginning of the string if it's the first match attempt).  So this acts like:

```
var\s+strings\s*=\s*[\s*"([^"]*)"
```

...on the first attempt, then:

```
,\s*"([^"]*)"
```

...after that, but each match has to start exactly where the last one left off.

Here's a [**demo in PHP**](http://ideone.com/brwIT), but it will work in Perl, too.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks... :-). But could you please explain why it didn't worked for `/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)+?/` ?

Comment: If you leave off the `g` from your Perl version, or call `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`, you'll see that you get the same results; you're actually only doing one match.  Within that match, the part in the capturing group gets applied multiple times, each time overwriting the result of the last pass.  I'm doing multiple matches, and saving the result of each match individually.

Answer (score 2):

You may prefer this solution which first looks for the string `var strings = [` using the `/g` modifier. This sets `\G` to match immediately after the `[` for the next regex, which looks for all immediately following occurrences of double-quoted strings, possibly preceded by commas or whitespace.

```
my @matches;

if ($str =~ /var \s+ strings \s* = \s* \[ /gx) {
  @matches = $str =~ /\G [,\s]* "([^"]+)" /gx;
}
```

Despite using the `/g` modifier your regex `/var strings = \[(?:\"(.+?)\",?)+/g` matches only once because there is no second occurrence of `var strings = [`. Each match returns a list of the values of the capture variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc. when the match completed, and `/(?:"(.+?)",?)+/` (there is no need to escape the double-quotes) captures multiple values into `$1` leaving only the final value there. You need to write something like the above , which captures only a single value into `$1` for each match.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `+` tells it to repeat the exact stuff inside brackets `(?:"(.+?)",?)` one or more times. So it will match the `"eee"` string, end then look for repetitions of that `"eee"` string, which it does not find.

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/var strings = \[(?:"(.+?)",?)+/)->explain();

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:var strings = \[(?:"(.+?)",?)+)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  var strings =            'var strings = '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,?                       ',' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

A simpler example would be:

```
my @m = ('abcd' =~ m/(\w)+/g);
print "@m";
```

Prints only `d`. This is due to:

```
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr/(\w)+/)->explain();

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(\w)+)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you use the quantifier on the capture group, only the last instance will be used.

---

Here's a way that works:

```
my $str = <<STR;
    ...
    ...
    var strings = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"];
    ...
    ...
STR

my @matches;
$str =~ m/var strings = \[(.+?)\]/; # get the array first
my $jsarray = $1;
@matches = $array =~ m/"(.+?)"/g; # and get the strings from that

print "@matches";
```

---

**Update**:
A single-line solution (though not a single regex) would be:

```
@matches = ($str =~ m/var strings = \[(.+?)\]/)[0] =~ m/"(.+?)"/g;
```

But this is highly unreadable imho.

Comment: Yeah, thats cool. Thanks. But is there any way it can be done in a single regex.

Comment: @Jithin for what reason you want single regex? it's hard to read and besides all small regexes work faster that single

Comment: @simbabque In the simple example you given, it matches only, _d_ because of the greediness. Changing your expression to `m/(\w)+?/g` will matches all, ie `a b c d`. But why it not worked for group regex in Question Update 2?

Comment: @loldop Its not about a single line regex. **Its about, why it didn't worked?** :-)

Comment: @Jithin: but so would `m/(\w)/g` - the `+` is the problem. I can't find it in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) at the moment.

Comment: @simbabque Search for "greed" in perlre.

Comment: @simbabque: Why ``m`` and ``s`` in one gulp?

Comment: @Jithin: Sorry, I cannot find a reference to "greed" regarding `/g` and parens in perlre. @Cylian: What do you mean? There's no `s///` in my post, is there?

Comment: @simbabque Check [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) for more explanation